# Globally rounding math in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering if there was a way of adding in a custom jQuery method or similar to ensure all calculations are rounded to the nearest integer? E.g. for working out widths etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Programming languages do not normally expose functionality to fundamentally break core behaviours.

Comment: what's the problem? widths can accept fractional values. If you really don't want one, then call `Math.round()` on the value before using it.

Comment: @user1737909 Can you please update us on where this issue stands?

Answer (score 2):

No, it would be impossible.

The closest you can do is change how calculations are performed in *jQuery* methods.

You can't change how the language itself performs arithmetic operations.

Operators can't be overriden in the JavaScript language.

Here is how you would over-ride jQuery's `.width` for example (this is not recommended for production code!)

```
$.fn.oldwidth = $.fn.width;
$.fn.width = function (elem) {
    if(elem == null){ // no param, getter
        return $.fn.oldwidth.call(this);
    }
    if (typeof elem === "string") { // 12px for example
        var numPart = parseInt(elem); //get just the 12
        var unitPart = elem.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).join(""); //get the number part
        return $.fn.oldwidth.call(this,Math.floor(numPart) + unitPart);
        }
        return $.fn.oldwidth.call(this,Math.floor(elem));
    }
```

#### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eB5sG/)

This would do:

```
$("#some").width("5.6em");
alert($("#some").width()); // Alerts 80 with the above code, 90 without.
```

Comment: Actually, in theory you could try to rewrite the JS prototypes to use different rounding. Which is a non-sense of course.

Comment: @ikaros45 I don't think you can, primitive value types (numbers being one) don't let you do this sort of thing, and you can't override how operations act on them, overriding something like valueOf wouldn't work on a value type, it's in the spec.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought JS would let you override operators too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of calculation you're trying to do, but if it's <strike>simple</strike> repetitive operations you can do a function that handle an operation and return the rounded result...

Like

```
function calculateSomething(operation){
// ???
return floor(result);
}
```

Comment: Why did you wrap `Math.floor` in a function? What advantage does this give over a regular call to `Math.floor` ?

Comment: I wrote "simple", i would say "repetitive".
Lol this code here is so stupid, thanks for pointing out.

I assumed he wanted to do the same task multiple times, but if it's a simple operation or something, you're right, a simple floor is enough...

Answer (score 0):

if you put all calculations in a specific class you could round them globally

```
var Arithmetics = //class of all calc's

for(each element in arithmetics){
    element = Math.round(element)
}
```